# Where to put R files that generate package data

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I am currently developing an R package and want it to be as clean as possible, so I try to resolve all WARNINGs and NOTEs displayed by `devtools::check()`.

One of these notes is related to some code I use for generating sample data to go with the package:

```
checking top-level files ... NOTE
Non-standard file/directory found at top level:
  'generate_sample_data.R'
```

It's an R script currently placed in the package root directory and not meant to be distributed with the package (because it doesn't really seem useful to include)

So here's my question: 
Where should I put such a file or how do I tell R to leave it be?
Is `.Rbuildignore` the right way to go?
Currently `devtools::build()` puts the R script in the final package, so I shouldn't just ignore the NOTE.

Comment: .Rbuildignore is the right place

Comment: I use `./data-raw/` (suggested by http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) for scripts that I need to keep for reproducibility (and updates) but do not need available to the end user. As you suggested, add that directory to `./.Rbuildignore` and you should have no problems.

Comment: @r2evans I searched the book before but didn't spot that. There's even a helper function for that in `devtools::use_data_raw()` to set it all up! Thanks for finding it. If you turn this into an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @LyzandeR If I want to experiment with some new methods to use in my R package, and I want to save R scripts to do with trying these new methods out. Would it also be a good idea to have these scripts within an experimental directory and add that directory name to the .Rbuildignore file? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html, it makes sense to use `./data-raw/` for scripts/functions that are necessary for creating/updating data but not something you need in the package itself. After adding `./data-raw/` to `./.Rbuildignore`, the package generation should ignore anything within that directory. (And, as you commented, there is a helper-function `devtools::use_data_raw()`.)

Comment: Is there a way to source those scripts periodically to modify the files that are moved to the `data` folder?

Comment: I don't know of anything in the `devtools` functions that automates this, I'm sure you could do something like `for (fn in list.files("path/to/data-raw", full.names=TRUE)) source(fn)`, assuming that those scripts "know" where to store their results. @spindoctor